# SSIS Package. Checking if tables exist, if not create if they do Truncate

Tags: c#, sql, ssis

I am brand new to SSIS and I have to create a SSIS package to migrate data from one database to another. I want to start off the package by checking if a number of tables exist in the destination database. If they do exist I want to truncate them if they don't I want to create them. Whats the best approach to doing this.

I have a simple query at the very top of the package to return all tables in the destination database

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
```

How do I pass these results to the next step to check if any of these table names are contained within a list or array of table names

Thanks

Comment: You may want to look at the [Transfer SQL Server Objects Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142159.aspx). You can configure it to drop and recreate the destination objects first if they exist, or just create if they don't.

Comment: Hi GarethD thanks for  the response. After the table checks are done and I want to do a simple data migration to the stage tables, I was wondering if an error is encountered at any stage of the data migration does step get rolled back?

Comment: I am not sure to be honest. What kind of error are you expecting?

Comment: Not expecting any but you know what these things are like they can come at any time. Tried googling it and i can't find anything to say what happens if a data flow task hits an error.

Comment: Rollback depends on your approach to transactions. By default, a taks and containers are at the `Supported` level meaning they will enlist an existing transaction but they won't create one of their own accord. If rollback functionality is desirable, then at your control flow (probably) you will set the package's Transaction to `Required`. Then all the subsequent tasks you add will just magically work (where magic is DTC Distributed Transaction Coordinator)

Comment: Use the Transaction in your T-SQL Code and it will make your life a whole lot easier. Transactions are good in SSIS, but IMHO they are better supported, handled and debugged in T-SQL. As for the error, you will have to build a package and see if it produces any. You cant taste the apple unless you bite it :P

Answer (score 7):

You need to use an `Execute SQL Task`, with pure T-SQL code. (More precisely: [Execute SQL Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141003.aspx) or [Execute T-SQL Statement Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms139753.aspx)).

In the `Execute  SQL Task` you need to specify which connection manager to use, and the SQL code to run.

The code inside the task should look like this:

```
IF EXISTS(
   SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
   WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE')
THEN
   TRUNCATE TABLE [BASE TABLE]
ELSE
   CREATE TABLE [BASE TABLE] (...)
END
```

This task is specified in the `Control flow` of the package and should include a constraint to run it before any data flow task tries to use the affected  tables.

Remember that not all tables can be truncated (if they have FKs) and that, if you're using `IDENTITY` PKs, they will increase on each run of your package. So, perhaps you should `DROP` the tables and `CREATE` then again on all the package executions. Take into account that you have to write the `CREATE TABLE` scripts anyway. (Of course, you shuould check if the table exists before dropping it).

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure there's a great way to do this out of the box in SSIS. There is however an alternative solution, BIML. It's got a slight learning curve but it's really simple once you get through it.

Actually, this tutorial seems like exactly what you're trying to do. And the nice thing about BIML is that you write it once and if you ever need it again, just a couple quick updates to re generate new packages. Super powerful. Give it a try. I'll be you will be surprised. http://bimlscript.com/Walkthrough/Details/73